# Beatifulsoup doesnt return href it returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
>>> soup_brand
<a data-role="BRAND" href="/URL/somename">
          Some Name
        </a>

>>> type(soup_brand)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

>>> print(soup_brand.get('href'))
None
```

Documentation followed: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Hi people from all over the world,
does someone now whats going wrong or am I targeting the object wrong ?

Need to get the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
soup.find_all(name="a")
```

or

```
soup.select_one(selector="a")
```

it should also be possible to catch with

```
all_anchor_tags = soup.find_all(name="a")
for tag in all_anchor_tags:
    print(tag.get("href")) #prints the href element of each a tag, thus each link
```

Although the all bs4 looks for multiple elemnts (the reason why we have a loop here) I encountered, that bs4 sometime is better in catching things, if you give it a search for all approach and then iterate over the elements

Answer (score 0):

in order to apply `['href']` the object must be `<bs4.Element.Tag>`.

so, try this:

```
string = \
"""
<a data-role="BRAND" href="/URL/somename">
          Some Name
        </a>
"""

s = BeautifulSoup(string)
a_tag = s.find('a')
print(a_tag["href"])
```

out

```
/URL/somename
```

or if you have multiple `a` tags you can try this:

```
a_tags = s.findAll('a')
for a in a_tags:
    print(a.get("href"))
```

out

```
/URL/somename
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked out. Your help is apreciated <3.

Comment: my pleasure to help.